# excel spreadsheet in servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

Hello,

I want to build excel spreadsheet with servlet programming. I used tab-separated data for excel.

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
out.println("\t\tFruits");
out.println("\tName\tPrice");
out.println("\tApples");
out.println("\tMangoes");
```

My query is that i want the title fruits to be in the center i mean i want to merge the cell. I want the output of Fruits from cell B2 to D2.What wld i have to update for merging the cell.
I know if we create a tabular data then it takes rowspan and colspan attribute but for this what to use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to produce a complete, fully compatibile Excel file you should use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) and create that file with this library. It's very easy to do - just take a look at the [guides here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).
And then you can use the code above to make a downloadable file for the user, i.e.:

```
public class Sample extends HttpServlet
{
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException
   {
    OutputStream out = null;
    try
    {
     response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

     response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=sampleName.xls");

     // Put your POI code here

    } catch (Exception e) {
     throw new ServletException("Exception in Excel Sample Servlet", e);
    } finally {
     if (out != null)
      out.close();
    }
   }
  }
```

There is a complete example of such servlet [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/04/16/poi_excel.html?page=2)

And if it can be XLSX file, you can use [this example](http://www.realdevelopers.com/blog/code/excel) as well.

But if You still want to use CSV/TSV files, you can still easily do so.

```
byte[] csv = dao.getYourContentHere();
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=data.csv"));
reponse.setContentLength(csv.length);
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.write(csv);
```

As one can see there is a difference in `Content-Disposition` section above.

BTW, if one wants to generate CSV data one can use a great little library from [Ostermiller](http://ostermiller.org/utils/CSV.html) which will format the CSV/TSV file in the way that Excel will understand fully.

Comment: Thanks i will just go thru ur explanation..If it's possible with the tab-separated data as i mentioned above to modify the code then pls let me know..what changes is to be done??

Comment: It is possible, but then You will create a TSV/CSV file, not an Excel file. And there is a difference, since CSV files are *imported* by Excel, not loaded. I will edit the answer to include that option...